# Nvidia mobile graphics card works only after additional restart

Tags: windows, drivers, graphics, nvidia

On my Alienware 13 R1 the integrated Nvidia GeForce GTX 860M does not work after cold-start.
When I boot for the first time and start a game it runs extremly slow. Also MSI Afterburner is not showing any statistics (frequency/temperature).
When I then do a reboot and try again it runs as fast as it should and MSI Afterburner is also showing its activities.

I'm using Win10 with all the latest updates and drivers.

Edit:
I figured out its about the power cable. I usually start the laptop then plug in the power adapter and then it doesn't work. When I plug it in before booting the graphics work already at the first start.
But when I boot and plug in the power adapter later the graphics never work.

Comment: You should update UEFI before anything else.

Comment: I already did a BIOS update to the latest version provided by Dell for this laptop.